# creating a table reference using the function tbl() in dyplyr

Tags: r, database, postgresql, dplyr, data-science

I have established a successful connection to a database when I'm trying to create a table reference by using the function`tbl()`.
Here's the code which I used:

```
 myredshiftconn<-src_postgres('nexus' , 
                             host = 'xxxxxxx.yyyyy-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
                             port=5439,
                             user="xxxx",
                             password="yyyyy")
```

Means that the connection establishes successfully.

However, after running the following code to create a table refrence another error occurs:

```
succesful_sales=tbl(myredshiftconn,"x_succesful_sales")
```

Here's error:

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  relation "x_succesful_sales" does not exist
```

)

What would be the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: The first question would have to be, does the table `x_successful_sales` exist with that exact casing in your `nexus` database? Double check that first. Also, does your user have rights to that table?

Comment: @gmiley myredshiftconn 
src:  postgres 8.0.2 [xxxxxx@txxxxxxx.yyyyy-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/nexus]
tbls: user_profile, x_succesful_sales

Comment: can you access `user_profile` table? Also, I am guessing you are logged in to the console using the same login credentials that your connection above uses? If that is the case, can you perform queries on `x_succesful_sales` table?

Comment: @gmiley same problem with user_profile, i don't access to redshift directly, i need to analyze data in R

Comment: @ph49 i would appreciate your help

Comment: @hadley i would appreciate your help